# i have 4 dropdowns and how can i edit and save the data mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i have 4 drop-downs, insert is working  and how can i edit the data and save the data to db mvc2. I got an error while update - The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedTimeZone' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable

```
My Controller

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
                return View(EventModel.Edit(id));

            }

            [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            [ValidateInput(false)] 
            public ActionResult Edit(int id, EventInfo EventInfo)
            {

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        EventModel.Edit(EventInfo);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    return View(EventInfo); 

            }

Model

    public SelectList TimeZones { get; set; }
            public SelectList EventType { get; set; }

            private string selectedTimeZone = "";
            public string SelectedTimeZone
            {
                get { return selectedTimeZone; }
                set { selectedTimeZone = value; }
            }


   Load Function



      myEventInfo.TimeZones = new SelectList(EventModel.getTIMEZOMES, "Key", "Value");
         myEventInfo.SelectedTimeZone = Datareader["TIMEZONE"].ToString();

    public static IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getTIMEZOMES
            {
                get
                {
                    Dbhelper DbHelper = new Dbhelper();
                    IList<KeyValuePair<String, String>> Timezone = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>();
                    DbCommand cmd = DbHelper.GetSqlStringCommond("SELECT * FROM TMP_TIMEZONES");
                    DbDataReader Datareader = DbHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd);
                    while (Datareader.Read())
                    {
                        Timezone.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>(Datareader["ABBR"].ToString(), Datareader["NAME"].ToString()));
                    }

                    return Timezone;
                }
            }

View page

     <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTimeZone, Model.TimeZones, "Select Timezone", new { style = "width:200px", @class = "textfield165" })%>
                            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedTimeZone)%>
```

I got an error while update / The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedTimeZone' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST action you forgot to populate the `TimeZones` property in case of error. Don't forget that only the selected timezone is POSTed, but not the list of timezones, so if you ever intend to redisplay the same view (for example in case of error) make sure you rebind this list (the same way you bound it in the GET action that allowed you to display the form on the first place):

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateInput(false)] 
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EventInfo EventInfo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        EventModel.Edit(EventInfo);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Here you must populate the TimeZones property before returning the view
    EventInfo.TimeZones = new SelectList(EventModel.getTIMEZOMES, "Key", "Value");
    return View(EventInfo); 
}
```

Comment: @sathishkumar, would you mind sharing how did you solve your problem? It might be helpful to other people having the same problem.